# how to print whitespaces like newline character '\n' to the screen in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, whitespace

I use Mac and python2, and I want to check which characters are considered as whitespaces by my operation system.

In IDLE, it returns '\t\n\x0b\x0c\r ', which is good.

But I use pycharm editor and when I use the following code:

```
import string
print string.whitespace
```

Then instead of getting the whitespace characters '\t\n\x0b\x0c\r ', I actually get a tab, a newline ect. characters printed.

How could I get my result in a form of string instead of the actual actions of these whitespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got you right. Do you want to see the representation like:

```
import string
print repr(string.whitespace)
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I want! Thank you jayme!

Comment: Thanks, just figured out how to do that